# Robocopy keep directory structure intact but include a large number of files

Tags: command-line, robocopy

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472692/how-to-copy-a-directory-structure-but-only-include-certain-files-using-windows) except I have a list of 370 files that have to be copied from source to destination.

So my initial directory looks like

```
folder1
  folder2
    folder3
      data.zip
      info.txt
      abc.xyz
    folder4
    folder5
      data.zip
      somefile.exe
      someotherfile.dll
```

and the destination should look like

```
copy_of_folder1
  folder2
    folder3
      data.zip
      info.txt
    folder4
    folder5
      data.zip
```

only it's not just data.zip and info.txt there are 370 files, if I type them all in it exceeds the command line length
I tried using a RCJ file like so:

> ROBOCOPY A:\ B:\ /JOB:thejob

I wrote this in thejob.rcj

> ```
> /IF       :: Include Files matching these names
> a.jar
> b.jar
> c.jar
> d.jar ...
> ```

But it doesn't work. Doesn't give me an error, but doesn't copy anything.

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way?  Does it give you an error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't copy anything